# How to improve website performance on iPad/iPhone?

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, performance, ipad

On an average computer animations work very smoothly. On iPad however jQuery animations like fade in (opacity from 0 to 1 over 0.5 sec) of 1920x1200px image seem to lag a bit.

Is there any way to speed that up? Any acceleration? Maybe I should disable processor consuming jQuery scripts for iPad? Are there any recommendations when coding for iPhone/iPad too?

I would also say that on older iPhones it lags far more.

UPDATE: The answer is CSS3.

Comment: Its all up to the processor. Give it lighter tasks. No need to include such an high res image, make it smaller

Comment: It's a great design, but I actually had a teensy bit of choppiness on my 2 year old macbook pro. I agree with Topener.

Comment: An 8-core Mac Pro running the latest Chrome chugs on that side drawer. Whatever you're doing here is ridiculously expensive even for a desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running Chrome -> Developer tools ->  Audits shows many improvements you can make without changing anything about the site's looks. After you finish those, try it again, then look at things like fewer tiles on iOS/Android, etc...

Looks like a  factor of at least 4 there, likely more...

--Tom

Comment: +1 - I wasn't aware of the Audits tool built into Chrome.  Pretty nice!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, that's useful. I already reduced number of animations, especially opacity animations and I got rid of really large images. I'll keep improving.